# what exactly do stack and mean in context of memory allocation

Tags: memory

I read things like "memory is allocated in a stack " or things like "these variable are placed in a heap ". I had once studied a book on microprocessor and can faintly remember that there had been topics or sections on something called as stack . And I do know that stacks also mean a kind of LIFO type data structure .

So , I feel confused as to what stacks imply . Are there memory locations in a every microprocessor other than the registers which are called as stack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe the most common situation.

In this context, stack is a dedicated memory for a program (more precisely, for a thread). This memory is allocated automatically by the operating system, when your program is started. Usually (but not always), stack is allocated from the main memory (so it is not a special memory in the CPU).

It's name is stack, because it is used "LIFO style". When a function is called, its local variables gets allocated from the stack ("pushed to the stack"). When it returns, these variables are freed ("pop from the stack").

About heap: heap is the place from where one can allocate memory in a more flexible manner than stack. Heap storage space is usually much larger than the stack. And the allocated space will be available even after the function (which allocated the space) returns. And for languages which doesn't have garbage collection, you have to manually free the allocated space. This heap is not to be confused with the data structure heap, which is a completely different thing.

```
char *var;
void example(int length) {
  char stackVar[1024]; // a 1024 element char array allocated on the stack
  char *heapVar = new char[length]; // a length sized variable allocated on the heap, and a pointer (heapVar) to this place allocated on the stack

  var = heapVar; // store a pointer to the allocated space

  // upon return, stackVar is automatically freed
  //              the pointer heapVar automatically freed
  //              the space that heapVar points to is not freed automatically, can be used afterwards (via the var pointer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again . What if I ask what grants these flexibility to heaps over stack ?

Comment: @MikhailTal: allocating from the stack is easy, it is just a pointer movement. With stack, you can only deallocate the last allocated memory area (you can only pop the last push). With heaps, you can do whatever you want. Allocate some memory, then some more, then free the first allocated. So the memory can have "holes" in it. Allocating from the heap involves sophisicated algorithms from the allocator side (to be fast, to avoid memory fragmentation, etc.)

Comment: And fragmentation occurs due to these wholes , right ?

Comment: @MikhailTal: mostly. You can read about this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)